# Query Mysql with multiple text strings on Shinyapp

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I would like to query different text strings through Mysql on a shiny app.

For example in the app below I would like to search the text string "data" and get all quotes with the word "data" from the quotes dataframe provided by `statquotes` library.

Furthermore, I would like to filter those quotes that contain certain words  eg "technique", "critical" using the OMIT input.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sqldf)
library(statquotes)

  data(quotes)
  quotes

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("TexSearch", tabName = "Tabs", icon = icon("object-ungroup"))) ),



dashboardBody(
   tabItem(tabName = "Tabs",
        fluidRow(
          column(width=3, 
                 box(
                   title="Search ",
                   solidHeader=TRUE,
                   collapsible=TRUE,
                   width=NULL,
                   submitButton("Search"),
                   textInput("wordsearch", "Search 1"),                       
                   textInput("wordomit", "OMIT"))),

          column( width=9,
                  tabBox(
                    width="100%",
                    tabPanel("tab1", 
                             htmlOutput("searchtext")
                    )))))))

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
         output$searchtext <- renderUI({
          if (input$wordsearch != "") {
            searches <- reactive({
                if (input$wordomit == "") {
                sqldf(paste0("SELECT  *
                           FROM quotes
                           WHERE text LIKE '%",input$wordsearch,"%'"))
                        } else {  

                sqldf(paste0("SELECT  *
                           FROM quotes
                           WHERE  (text LIKE '%",input$wordsearch,"%'
                           AND text NOT LIKE '%",input$wordomit,"%' )"))

                  }
                  }) 


     output = ""
        relevantquotes <- searches()
       if (dim(relevantquotes)[1] < 100) {
        output <-
            paste(output,
            "<b>Number of quotes: ",
            as.character(dim(relevantquotes)[1]),
            "</b>.<br/>")
    for (i in seq(from = 1,
                  to = dim(relevantquotes)[1])) {
      output <- paste(output,
                   paste("qid: ", relevantquotes[i, "qid"]),
                   sep = "<br/><br/>")
      output <- paste(output,
                   paste("topic: ", relevantquotes[i, "topic"]),
                   sep = "<br/><br/>")
      output <- paste(output,

                     paste("text: ", relevantquotes[i, "text"]),
                   sep = "<br/><br/><br/>")

    }

  }
  HTML(output)
   }
   })

   }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Currently, I can only omit one term at a time. Is there a way I can combine different words to omit through one textInput.
I tried this method below without success:

```
omit <-    stringr::str_c(stringr::str_c("'", input$wordomit, "'"), collapse = ',')
```

the insert in the query like below:

```
sqldf(paste0("SELECT  *    
                FROM quotes
                WHERE (text LIKE '%",input$wordsearch,"%'
                AND text  NOT IN (",omit,") )
```

Since I am using a database, the query language in my app is `MySQL` but I use `sqldf` for this reproducible example

Comment: You should really consider using FULLTEXT indexes and [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead .. the boolean mode makes it much more easy.. `MATCH() AGAINST('+word -omit' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` as -> `+ stands for AND

    - stands for NOT

    [no operator] implies OR`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I had tried that too, but I couldn't find the right syntax for shiny environment, especially when passing the user inputs to the queries